# how to move windows cursor by phone accelerometer smoothly

Tags: android, cursor, accelerometer, sensors

i am trying to move windows cursor with android phone accelerometer, but i don't know how to properly use data to move cursor smoothly.
I use wifi to transfer data from phone to laptop.

Here is some code without wifi and socket transfer code, please give me some idea or correct my code.
Android:
onCreate:

```
sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
accelerometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
```

I am using only X and Y coordinates:

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        x =  event.values[0];
        y =  event.values[1];
```

Then i use this function in windows, that moves cursor from one to other position by steps:
Params: x1,x2 - from position, x2,y2 - to position, t - time, n - steps

```
public void mouseGlide(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int t, int n) {
    try {
        Robot r = new Robot();
        double dx = (x2 - x1) / ((double) n);
        double dy = (y2 - y1) / ((double) n);
        double dt = t / ((double) n);
        for (int step = 1; step <= n; step++) {
            Thread.sleep((int) dt);
            r.mouseMove((int) (x1 + dx * step), (int) (y1 + dy * step));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Basically i want to use phone tilt to move cursor as same as when i use mouse, photoshere in camera apps moves smoothly.

I do not know how to do it.